# How should I preserve and repopulate form data when opening a sub-form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In an MVC4 project, I have a form that contains a partial view which is an index view of languages studied at school. It is a default type view template index, with Add, Delete, Edit links per row etc. When you Add or Edit, it opens an Add or Edit view for a Language. After e.g. adding a language, the updated partial view is returned.

My problem is that if the user opens the Language form, edits and captures on the main form will be lost. I can't just do an Ajax save before opening the Language form, as the main form may only be partially complete and fail validation. What I am thinking of doing though is using an `AjaxPreserve` action that takes a `FormCollection`, and stores it in session (o on disk, or anywhere) and therefore no model binding and server validation is performed.

I then have two problems: I will need to disable client validation before calling the AJAX action, and I will need to repopulate the main form using the `FormCollection` I saved earlier. I think there should surly be some jQuery voodoo to disable client validation, but I am completely stumped on repopulating the form.

*ALTERNATE SOLUTION*: Instead of using 'sub-forms', I can use editor templates, in pop-ip forms, where the FK IDs are not required, but that us only in certain cases, so my question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple make the sub request for adding language using Ajax and repopulate the dropdown or what ever way you are accepting language on the main form on sucessfully save.

**This will save a lot of effort. **

Comment: I am busy trying a method where I use a table row as a form, and when submitted for edit or create, then return the whole table as a partial from an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use something like Knockout where you create javascript model and bind it to a grid/dialog edit/template view. I would transform the whole data to a JS model, bind it to a table/grid and then track all changes on the client side. When all is done, just serialize the whole model back to the server and update the data store.
If this is an acceptable scenario, it will save you a lot of trouble.
Familiarity with Knockout is required, but if you've used it before, you will be able to solve this in a very clean and efficient way.

This example on the Knockout website gives an idea of what I'm trying to suggest. Editing, deleting, adding is done on the client side until you send all of the data back to the server. You will need to track flags for each object to know if it's added, edited or deleted.

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use javascript?
E.g. You have main form, that stores some data. And when you need to add something specific like languages you open popup using partial view, allow user to fill form, but when user press submit you intercept action with js, save stuff to javascript array/object or whatever else and maybe store it in a hidden field of main form - for final submit

```
var newData = new Object();
newData.Field1 = $("#yourField1");
...
lanuageData.push(newData);
$("#languageContainer").val(JSON.stringify(languageData));
...
```

DataAnnotation validation works here as well like:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("your_partial_view_container");
```

When you need to edit some object that was already added to js array - open popup and fill it up with element of you js array. So basically you do all CRUD on client-side, saving changes only on final submit.
To make your code in a conrolller more clear you can use custom model binder which deserialize some string field from JSon to List or any other kind of object -> so it can be validated on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Would saving your values to local storage be acceptable? What about using TempData?

Comment: Let's say I don't know anything about local storage or TempData. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Sure. HTML 5 has introduced something neat called web storage.  It's an improvement above using cookies and will work on the client side. You can read about it here. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Temp data allows you to pass data from one page to the next. It lasts for only one request and happens on the server side. You can read more about it here. http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications